# How to create a new log file for values in Jira

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am current using the following code for my Jira plugin, it is a fragment with a REST endpoint. Here is the code for my REST endpoint below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl
import com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties
import com.atlassian.sal.api.UrlMode
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import Helper


@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate
def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")
def bulkSplitterHashMap= Helper.getBulkSplitterHashMap()
int iTracSuperFeatureSplitterIssueTypeID = bulkSplitterHashMap["iTracSuperFeatureSplitterIssueTypeID"] ;
int iTracSuperFeatureSplitterProjectID =  bulkSplitterHashMap["iTracSuperFeatureSplitterProjectID"] ;
String iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL =bulkSplitterHashMap["iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL"];



callBulkSplitter(httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["jira-users"]) {
  MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->
  def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext?.loggedInUser
  def issueId = queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long
  Issue myissue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(issueId)
  def issueKey = myissue.getKey()
  def project = myissue.getProject()
  def baseUrl = ScriptRunnerImpl.getOsgiService(ApplicationProperties).getBaseUrl(UrlMode.ABSOLUTE)
  def iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL2 = iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL.replaceAll(":1:", issueKey)
  def iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL3 = iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL2.replaceAll(":2:", user.getUsername())
  def projectID = project.get("id")
  int projectIDInt = projectID as int
  if (iTracSuperFeatureSplitterProjectID == projectIDInt && iTracSuperFeatureSplitterIssueTypeID == Long.valueOf(myissue.getIssueTypeId())) {
    log.warn("The rest endpoint has been executed by the user " +user)
    Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(iTracSuperFeatureSplitterURL3)).build()
  }

}
```

I am using the following statement to log some values for testing:

```
def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")
```

I am also using this statement for printing the values that I would like to test:

```
log.warn("The rest endpoint has been executed by the user " +user)
```

I would like to use a new log called **itrac-pulgins** and I tried simply replacing the line **`def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")`** with **`def log = Logger.getLogger("itrac-plugins.log")`** but it didn't work. How can I create a new log called **itrac-pulgins** where I can print my debugging statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a new log file? For that you would have to update the log4j configuration within your JIRA manually.